# Clarification on Hatch and slack pathway

Tags: biochemistry, botany, plant-physiology, photosynthesis

The following is a minor clarification that I want to make, since it is rarely addressed directly in most of the texts I have gone through.

In **C₄** pathway, the chloroplasts are dimorphic, that is, the bundle sheath chloroplasts contain **RuBisCO**, but lack grana and can hence perform only the light-independent reactions. The mesophyll chloroplasts lack **RuBisCO** but contain the granal apparatus to perform light reactions for synthesis of **ATP** and **NADPH**. The bundle sheath cells are impervious to gaseous transport (to prevent the entry of **O₂**), but recieve the required **CO₂** by the intake of an organic acid produced by **CO₂** fixation by the mesophyll cells.

> But, to effect the Calvin cycle in the bundle sheath cells, it
>   requires a high concentration of the light reaction products, i.e.,
>   **ATP** and **NADPH**. Since they themselves lack grana, they must obtain the required share from elsewhere. Where do they obtain it
>   from?

My guess is that **NADPH** enters the bundle sheath cell with the organic acid primarily produced in the mesophyll cells where light reaction occurs. **ATP** is met by a similar uptake plus the utilisation of the ATP produced by respiration. I need to confirm this as it is usually never addressed in texts.

Comment: I guess they go via plasmodesmata.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the source of ATP but I can tell you something about NADPH.

The conversion of malate to pyruvate and CO₂ by malic enzyme is carried out in the bundle sheath cell. This process produces NADPH.

Answer (score 1):

See the very 1st thing is bundle sheath cell shows very less concentration of Grana, hence we say Grana is absent,  the required amount of ATP & NADPH₂ are also transported from mesophyll cell to bundle sheath cell via plasmodesmata.